# How to upload multiple images in django model

Tags: django

I have been struggling trying to create Post model which allows user to upload multiple images. Assuming that every publication is a row in post model, I guess, we should store images for each publication in single table cell in its row (sorry for redundancy, I just want to make sure that nobody gets me wrong). Is it possible and is it a right way to do this?
Also, maybe I should make N image fields in model and make it look for user like he fills one form field in frontend and at that time images are being put into other hidden image fields?

Sorry, if I am being dumb, I am new to django. I appreciate any advice!

Comment: to summarise, you want to know the best way to create models that allow a 'post' to have multiple images?

Comment: @Danoram, yes that's it

Comment: By the way, I already have an idea to store images in separate table with columns post_id and image_id, where every row is image for post, but i am worried that one day this table might grow too huge and it will slow down performance. Please tell me if i am wrong

Comment: I'm sure that if you're going to one day have hundreds or thousands of images performance should be fine

Comment: That's good :). But what if it grows to hundreds of thousands? Will it be ok too?

Comment: that's what I'm saying